# Onchange Event in JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me. I need to change a textbox value when i give value in another textbox. see i have three text box first one is Qty another Amount and third will be a Total Amount.
here i will give a value for Qty and amount. Now third textbox i mean Total amount will be appear automatically.

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You use the `change` event to monitor your first two inputs. Then you use the `val` method to get and set the property values.

http://jsfiddle.net/8hunC/

```
$('#qty, #amount').change( function(){
    var total = $('#qty').val() * $('#amount').val();
    $('#total').val(total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has an `oninput` event that would serve this purpose. You'd need to use events like `onfocus`, `onkeypress` and `onblur` in conjunction to achieve a similar level of responsiveness in older browsers, though. Or, if it's not essential that these values be updated with every keystroke, you can simply use the `onchange` event to update the value whenever the user changes, then blurs the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xMjdR/3/